# What is the best way to find research groups in my field?

Tags: phd, research-process, application, supervision, research-group

I seek to find research groups in my field, start a dialogue with potential supervisors, and apply for available positions. In other words, I want to check research groups' web pages mainly, not just professors' information on university websites. What is the best way to optimize my research?

Comment: I would guess that most "research groups" are informal and don't have an online presence. Maybe an internal mailing list. The best place to find them is at conferences, but that might not be open to you.

Comment: If you already are in a field, you should already have some ideas. And the supervisors / teachers you had until now can certainly help you.

Comment: Are you applying for a PhD or a postdoc?

Comment: @FedericoPoloni For a PhD

Comment: Please add this info to your question!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are already in a field or have decided what field you want to be in. I started by thinking through (or looking through) the papers I had written at that point, and identified the people or groups of people I cited often, or those whose papers I enjoyed reading.
Make a short list including their institutional affiliation from their papers. For some this will then be an easy step to searching out their lab group website at their university, or a link to an externally hosted site. Some may have a 'lab group' on researchgate.  ​
For those who do not, look them up in a database and see who they co-author with most often or most recently. This may help you identify their group even if they do not have a formal online presence.

In terms of starting a dialogue and applying for available positions - this depends what stage you are at and what field you are in. If you were looking to postdoc in my field, that initial conversation would include some fellowship or funding examples I was looking to apply for to come to their lab. You need to be thinking about what you are bringing them from the get go.

Comment: For a Phd, you still need to find out what the funding model is for Phd's in your target countries. This varies a lot and it will help you stand out to a potential advisor or avoid wasting your time. In some places, if they aren't advertising they don't have funding to support a position. In that case, bringing external funding could work, but not always. Take the time to do your research.